# How to implement custom conventions in ODataConventionModelBuilder

Tags: c#, odata, data-annotations

When targeting an OData v4 service, I want to perform string length validation on the client side to prevent round data trips to the API, however I do not want to hand-code each input field if the information can be passed through the $metadata.

It turns out that the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` does correctly interpret `MaxLengthAttribute` on data classes and set the appropriate `EdmProperty` values, but it does not have a corresponding convention for interpreting `StringLengthAttribute`. The following snippet from `$metadata` shows the expected output for a given hypothetical class definition:

```xml
<EntityType Name="NoteType">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Title" MaxLength="100" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Description" MaxLength="500" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
</EntityType>
```

```cs
public class NoteType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

> Note that `Description` is annotated with the `MaxLengthAttribute` but `Title` is using `StringLengthAttribute`

The actual output in the $metadata does not include the `MaxLength` for the `Title` property:

```xml
<EntityType Name="NoteType">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Description" MaxLength="500" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
</EntityType>
```

I cannot make changes to the data class definitions as they are derived from 3rd party assemblies so I am looking for a generic solution to correctly configure all properties in the *EdmModel* with an appropriate `MaxLength` attribute if the data property has a `StringLengthAttribute` that defines a `MaxLength`.

In EF6 and EFCore I am used to implementing custom *conventions* to implement business rules in the DbContext, given that the name of the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` has the word *convention* in it, I was expecting to be able define my own conventions and *plug them in* to the pipeline. but I cannot find a good example on how to do this.

Comment: There is an open FeatureRequest at github: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/658